# How to encompass LibreOffice apps in the "Applications" tab so that they come under 1 banner which is "LibreOffice"?

Tags: libreoffice

Whenever I need to open up a LibreOffice application say, the Writer, it's there in the Applications tab alright. But what my problem is that there are 6 LibreOffice apps in total, and they eat a lot of space in the Applications drawer. Is there any way I can put them into one single folder-like thingy for example Office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The applications menu doesn't support folders at this time.